# Fetch data from Mysql database table with asp.net core 2.0 Web Api

Tags: mysql, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on Angular 2 Project. I have a table on Mysql database. I have connected to my database. Now, I want to fetch data from my Mysql database table. How can I fetch data from database with asp.net core 2.0 Web Api???

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using SQL Server. Express version should do it. You should also check EntityFramework.

Check [this one](http://insidemysql.com/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-and-mysql-connectornet/).

```
[Route("API/my-api-url")]
public class MyController : Controller
{

    public async Task<IActionResult> List()
    {
        List<Film> list = new List<Film>();

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM film", conn);
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add(new Film()
                    {
                        FilmId = reader.GetInt32("film_id"),
                        Title = reader.GetString("title"),
                        Description = reader.GetString("description"),
                        ReleaseYear = reader.GetInt32("release_year"),
                        Length = reader.GetInt32("length"),
                        Rating = reader.GetString("rating")
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return new JsonResult(list);
    }
}
```